# Image from JSON file to React JS file not displaying

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have a JSON file that contains an image source. I am trying to display the image, but it doesn't seem to display. I do not get any errors in the console or in the browser.

JSON File:

```js
[
  {
    "PageLink": "/casestudy/text-healthcare",
    "title": "text healthcare website",
    "id": "text-healthcare",
    "imgSrc": "../assets/work/text-hp.png",
    "alt": "text healthcare",
    "contentClass": "some text..."
  },
  {
    "PageLink": "/casestudy/text2-healthcare",
    "title": "text2 healthcare website",
    "id": "text2-healthcare",
    "imgSrc": "../assets/work/text2-hp.png",
    "alt": "text2 healthcare",
    "contentClass": "some text too..."
  }
]
```

Here is where I am calling the JSON data in my JS file where `CaseStudyData` is how I am importing the JSON data into the JS file:

```html
<FeatureBlock pageLink={CaseStudyData[0].PageLink}
              title={CaseStudyData[0].title}
              id={CaseStudyData[0].id} 
              imgSrc={CaseStudyData[0].imgSrc}
              alt={CaseStudyData[0].alt}
              contentClass={CaseStudyData[0].contentClass} />
<FeatureBlock pageLink={CaseStudyData[1].PageLink}
              title={CaseStudyData[1].title} 
              id={CaseStudyData[1].id} 
              imgSrc={CaseStudyData[1].imgSrc} 
              alt={CaseStudyData[1].alt} 
              contentClass={CaseStudyData[1].contentClass} />
```

Everything else is loading just fine except the image. It is able to retrieve the data and display it. The path to the image is correct as I have verified already.

Here is the path it displays in console which is the right path but the image is no displaying. It says "http://localhost:3000/assets/work/text-hp.png"

Comment: When you call the url path to the image directly, are you able to view it?
Have you checked the value of the property in FeatureBlock in your web browser's Development Tools?

Comment: Check the network tab in your developer tools and filter by 'Media'.  Are the images failing to load? if so where are they trying to load from?

Comment: @needoriginalname I am not able to view it. So the static paths are changing to dynamic paths when I see the image through the standard mark up. :(

Comment: Any luck? What's in the network tab?

Comment: @Mark No luck. the imgSrc being passed in from the JSON file is passing as a string. :( The image paths get generated dynamically when I load the website and I don't know how to do that from JSON to my JS file.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you set up your webpack config yourself?  If so you're going to need to install `url-loader`

`npm install -D url-loader`

and then update your webpack config with this

```
{
  test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 8192,
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        publicPath: 'assets/' // or whatever the path you're using for assets is
      },
    },
  ],
},
```